# Terminal: go through autocompleted options after pressing tab

Tags: macos, terminal, autocomplete, linux-terminal

Pressing tab on terminal shows the possibilities you can choose from like below:

```
MacBook :~ user$ ls _ 
Directory1 Directory2 Directory3
```

How can I make the possibilities appear on the cursor (the underscore next to ls above ) so I can just switch or navigate between them using arrows or anything else, instead of typing them.
The idea here that some directories may start with Arabic letters (usually appears as ??) so it is easier to navigate through all the possibilities rather than  just showing them and try typing them.

Comment: If you type the first character `D` then _Tab_ will expand on the command line as many characters as are unique (in your example `Directory`), and a second _Tab_ shows the new list. You can keep doing this a character at a time until the file you want is expanded, when a blank is appended, so you can start to type the next parameter. I don't know how non-Ascii characters are handled, though.

Answer (score 2):

What you search can be acieved by the following (I assume you work in a `bash` shell since you used the OSX tag):

```
bind 'TAB:menu-complete'
```

If you want to have both use add that:

```
bind 'set show-all-if-ambiguous on'
```

Comment: Very useful settings. I didn't know about them, so thanks very much.